# Is there an API to get the price of Apple's subscription?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, subscription, server-to-server

I tried the subscription-related API mentioned in the Apple documentation, but I found that there is no price of income-related fields in the response body.

Is there such an API that allows me to get the price of product subscriptions from the server-side?

Answer (score 0):

sadly there is no api that include price due to privacy issues like revealing user's region info.